Regex to match symbols like ┼, ▓, ┐, ╔, ╠, ═, ╩, �
I have a requirement to find if a string has symbols like ┼, ▓, ┐, ╔, ╠, ═, ╩, � etc. Is there a regex to find the symbols like these?
Basically, a string can have English letters, Latin letters, numbers, punctuation marks but not some unknown character.
I am currently using this [^\u0020-\u007E\u00A0-\u00FF]+
But it also matches this- QLF feat. ARGJOW & M€RAH & NEMO. This text is fine as € is Euro symbol.

All these chars are from Symbol, Other Unicode category. So, \p{So}? Or, ^\P{So}*$ if you need to validate the whole string?

"symbols like ┼, ▓, ┐, ╔, ╠, ═, ╩, � etc": what is the etc here? Can't you just look up the unicode ranges you want to include/exclude?

Well, if you could explain your problem clearer, show your code and say where the issue is, we could be more helpful.

@WiktorStribiżew Thanks, your first comment was helpful. Thats what I needed. Our clients complained about such symbols. They wanted a list of texts which had such symbols. None of them actually has the full list of symbols.

If you are trying to match 'symbols' that are only the result of combining multiple code points (such as  or ☺️) you can only do that with a regex engine that supports \X to match logical grapheme clusters.

Using this Unicode character converter (no affiliation), you can easily check the Unicode category that specific symbols belong to.
The ┼, ▓, ┐, ╔, ╠, ═, ╩, � characters all belong to Symbol, Other Unicode category.
You can match them with the  \p{So} regex pattern.
Currently, it matches 6639 Unicode code points, and you can use the following regex to match them if \p{So} is not supported:
[\u00A6\u00A9\u00AE\u00B0\u0482\u058D\u058E\u060E\u060F\u06DE\u06E9\u06FD\u06FE\u07F6\u09FA\u0B70\u0BF3-\u0BF8\u0BFA\u0C7F\u0D4F\u0D79\u0F01-\u0F03\u0F13\u0F15-\u0F17\u0F1A-\u0F1F\u0F34\u0F36\u0F38\u0FBE-\u0FC5\u0FC7-\u0FCC\u0FCE\u0FCF\u0FD5-\u0FD8\u109E\u109F\u1390-\u1399\u166D\u1940\u19DE-\u19FF\u1B61-\u1B6A\u1B74-\u1B7C\u2100\u2101\u2103-\u2106\u2108\u2109\u2114\u2116\u2117\u211E-\u2123\u2125\u2127\u2129\u212E\u213A\u213B\u214A\u214C\u214D\u214F\u218A\u218B\u2195-\u2199\u219C-\u219F\u21A1\u21A2\u21A4\u21A5\u21A7-\u21AD\u21AF-\u21CD\u21D0\u21D1\u21D3\u21D5-\u21F3\u2300-\u2307\u230C-\u231F\u2322-\u2328\u232B-\u237B\u237D-\u239A\u23B4-\u23DB\u23E2-\u2426\u2440-\u244A\u249C-\u24E9\u2500-\u25B6\u25B8-\u25C0\u25C2-\u25F7\u2600-\u266E\u2670-\u2767\u2794-\u27BF\u2800-\u28FF\u2B00-\u2B2F\u2B45\u2B46\u2B4D-\u2B73\u2B76-\u2B95\u2B97-\u2BFF\u2CE5-\u2CEA\u2E50\u2E51\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u2FF0-\u2FFF\u3004\u3012\u3013\u3020\u3036\u3037\u303E\u303F\u3190\u3191\u3196-\u319F\u31C0-\u31E3\u31EF\u3200-\u321E\u322A-\u3247\u3250\u3260-\u327F\u328A-\u32B0\u32C0-\u33FF\u4DC0-\u4DFF\uA490-\uA4C6\uA828-\uA82B\uA836\uA837\uA839\uAA77-\uAA79\uFD40-\uFD4F\uFDCF\uFDFD-\uFDFF\uFFE4\uFFE8\uFFED\uFFEE\uFFFC\uFFFD\U00010137-\U0001013F\U00010179-\U00010189\U0001018C-\U0001018E\U00010190-\U0001019C\U000101A0\U000101D0-\U000101FC\U00010877\U00010878\U00010AC8\U0001173F\U00011FD5-\U00011FDC\U00011FE1-\U00011FF1\U00016B3C-\U00016B3F\U00016B45\U0001BC9C\U0001CF50-\U0001CFC3\U0001D000-\U0001D0F5\U0001D100-\U0001D126\U0001D129-\U0001D164\U0001D16A-\U0001D16C\U0001D183\U0001D184\U0001D18C-\U0001D1A9\U0001D1AE-\U0001D1EA\U0001D200-\U0001D241\U0001D245\U0001D300-\U0001D356\U0001D800-\U0001D9FF\U0001DA37-\U0001DA3A\U0001DA6D-\U0001DA74\U0001DA76-\U0001DA83\U0001DA85\U0001DA86\U0001E14F\U0001ECAC\U0001ED2E\U0001F000-\U0001F02B\U0001F030-\U0001F093\U0001F0A0-\U0001F0AE\U0001F0B1-\U0001F0BF\U0001F0C1-\U0001F0CF\U0001F0D1-\U0001F0F5\U0001F10D-\U0001F1AD\U0001F1E6-\U0001F202\U0001F210-\U0001F23B\U0001F240-\U0001F248\U0001F250\U0001F251\U0001F260-\U0001F265\U0001F300-\U0001F3FA\U0001F400-\U0001F6D7\U0001F6DC-\U0001F6EC\U0001F6F0-\U0001F6FC\U0001F700-\U0001F776\U0001F77B-\U0001F7D9\U0001F7E0-\U0001F7EB\U0001F7F0\U0001F800-\U0001F80B\U0001F810-\U0001F847\U0001F850-\U0001F859\U0001F860-\U0001F887\U0001F890-\U0001F8AD\U0001F8B0\U0001F8B1\U0001F900-\U0001FA53\U0001FA60-\U0001FA6D\U0001FA70-\U0001FA7C\U0001FA80-\U0001FA88\U0001FA90-\U0001FABD\U0001FABF-\U0001FAC5\U0001FACE-\U0001FADB\U0001FAE0-\U0001FAE8\U0001FAF0-\U0001FAF8\U0001FB00-\U0001FB92\U0001FB94-\U0001FBCA]

